# Flutter handling canvas.saveLayer to make layers

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, flutter-canvas

I'm trying to make layer function like Photoshop in flutter.
For simple implementation, all pictures in a layer are the same color. For example, all drawings on layer 1 are red.
But each layer has a different color. For example, layer 1 is red and layer 2 is blue.

Below is the structure of the layers.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:label_up_study/models/sketch.dart';
import 'dart:math';

Color randomColor() {
  return Color((Random().nextDouble() * 0xFFFFFF).toInt()).withOpacity(1.0);
}

class LayerInfo {
  List<Sketch> drawLayer; // This stores every sketch in Listener onPointerDown()/Move()/Up()
  String label;
  bool selected;
  bool visible;
  Color color;

  LayerInfo({
    required this.drawLayer,
    required this.label,
    required this.selected,
    this.visible = true,
    required this.color,
  });
}

class Layers {
  final Map<int, LayerInfo> layers = {};

  int get selected =>
      layers.keys.where((key) => layers[key]!.selected).toList().first;

  void addLayer() {
    final nextKey = layers.keys.toList().last + 1;
    layers.updateAll((key, value) {
      value.selected = false;
      return value;
    });
    layers[nextKey] = LayerInfo(
        drawLayer: [],
        label: 'Layer $nextKey',
        selected: true,
        color: randomColor());
  }

  Layers() {
    layers[1] = LayerInfo(
        drawLayer: [], label: 'Layer 1', selected: true, color: randomColor());
  }
}
```

I tested canvas.saveLayer like this and this is how I want it to behave: [image: -]

There's no overlay with the same layer, but it is distinct with other layer.

So I expected it workes same at below code

```
class WholeSketchPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Layers imageLayer;

  WholeSketchPainter({required this.imageLayer});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (var value in imageLayer.layers.values) {
      print(value.color);
      if (value.visible) {
        canvas.saveLayer(null, Paint()..color = value.color.withOpacity(0.5));
        drawSketch(canvas, value.drawLayer, value.color);
        canvas.restore();
      } else {
        // nothing
      }
    }
  }

  void drawSketch(Canvas canvas, List<Sketch> sketches, Color layerColor) {
    Paint strokePaint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..color = layerColor.withOpacity(1);
    Paint fillPaint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..color = layerColor.withOpacity(1);

    for (int i = 0; i < sketches.length; i++) {
      final offsets = sketches[i].points;
      if (offsets.isEmpty) {
        return;
      }
      final path = Path();
      final firstOffset = offsets.first;
      final lastOffset = offsets.last;

      path.moveTo(firstOffset.dx, firstOffset.dy);

      if (sketches[i].sketchType == SketchType.pencil) {
        for (int i = 1; i < offsets.length - 1; i++) {
          final p0 = offsets[i];
          final p1 = offsets[i + 1];
          path.quadraticBezierTo(
              p0.dx, p0.dy, (p0.dx + p1.dx) / 2, (p0.dy + p1.dy) / 2);
        }
        canvas.drawPath(path, fillPaint);
      } else if (sketches[i].sketchType == SketchType.square) {
        final rect = Rect.fromPoints(firstOffset, lastOffset);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, fillPaint);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(WholeSketchPainter delegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

BUT IT DOESN'T. It keeps pop up the below layer and cover it.

This is what it looks like with one layer
[image]

And this is what it looks like with two layers. Color is overlapped, and there's no clip between layers.
[image]

I want the WholeSketcher code act like the first one, but I have no idea how should I do. Are there any solution to do it? Or anyother way to do it??

+) overall painting code had reference on this: https://github.com/JideGuru/flutter_drawing_board/tree/master

Comment: while doing `canvas.saveLayer(null, Paint()..color = value.color.withOpacity(0.5));`, try adding BlendMode to the Paint object.

Comment: Nothing change but color. I tried Blendmode.multiply but only color changes, there's no clip area